# Tomcat JDBC - connection where SQLException happen not reused by pool

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

I use Tomcat JDBC connection pool for PostgreSQL.

Pool configuration

```
<Resource name="jdbc/pg_mega" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:6432/db"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        username="***" password="****"
        defaultAutoCommit="true"
        initialSize="1"
        maxActive="300"
        maxTotal="300"
        maxIdle="20"
        minIdle="5"
        maxWait="10000"
        validationQuery="select 1"
        validationInterval="30000"
        testWhileIdle="false"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testOnReturn="false"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
        />
```

Part of Java code

```
Connection c = null;
Statement s = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
DataSource ds = ... Get DataSource  ...

while(running) {

    if (c == null) {
        try {
            c = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException exi) { env.l.pe(exi); }
    }
    try {
        s = c.createStatement();
        rs = s.executeQuery(q);
    } catch (SQLException sec) {
        // close resources
        if (rs != null) {
            try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException sec2) { env.l.pe(sec2); }
            rs = null;
        }
        if (s != null) {
            try { s.close(); } catch (SQLException sec2) { env.l.pe(sec2); }
            s = null;
        }
        if (c != null) {
            try { c.close(); } catch (SQLException sec2) { env.l.pe(sec2); }
            c = null;
        }
        continue;
    }
    finally {
    ... close connection, statement, resultset...
    }
}
```

If Exception happen while `s.executeQuery(q)` I will close Connection, Statement, ResultSet and try connect once again (after loop continue).

As I see in JDBC pool activity, Active connection increase each time Exception happen.

Do you know, how can I free db connection for pool which ends with an exception?

May be this is bug?

Comment: So, you repeat the same closing technique in `catch` and in `finally`? Why not just use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)? i.e. `try (c = ds.getConnection(); s = c.createStatement(); rs = s.executeQuery(q)) {...}`

Comment: I simplify code. Originally in finally part some extra code which must execute if try success.

Comment: Well, not properly closed connections *could* cause this.

Comment: May I have incorrect use of pool.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you close the connection in the catch ? You could/should use the same connection and just close it in the finally, outside of the while loop.

Watch out : your code could do an infinite loop, if your query is malformed for example, or if your database is not reachable.

I would recommend you not to do this while loop and just do n retries (3 for example) with a wait time between each try.